# Logstash logs are read but are not pushed to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have the following logstash configuration:

```
input {
  file {
    codec => "json_lines"
    path => ["/etc/logstash/input.log"]
    sincedb_path => "/etc/logstash/dbfile"
    start_position => "beginning"
    ignore_older => "0"
  }
}
output {
   elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["192.168.169.46:9200"]
   }
   stdout {
      codec => rubydebug
   }
}
```

The `/etc/logstash/input.log` file is populated with logs from a running java application. The logs are in the following json format (they are written inline separated by the `\n` character):

```
{
"exception": {
    "exception_class": "java.lang.RuntimeException",
    "exception_message": "Test runtime exception stack: 0",
    "stacktrace": "java.lang.RuntimeException: Test runtime exception stack: 0"
},
"@version": 1,
"source_host": "WS-169-046",
"message": "Test runtime exception stack: 0",
"thread_name": "parallel-1",
"@timestamp": "2019-12-02T16:30:14.084+02:00",
"level": "ERROR",
"logger_name": "nl.hnf.logs.aggregator.demo.LoggingTest",
"aplication-name": "demo-log-aggregation"
}
```

I also updated the logstash default template using the elasticsearch API(Put request body at: `http://192.168.169.46:9200/_template/logstash?pretty`):

```
{
"index_patterns": "logstash-*",
"version": 60002,
"settings": {
    "index.refresh_interval": "5s",
    "number_of_shards": 1
},
"mappings": {
    "dynamic_templates": [
        {
            "message_field": {
                "path_match": "message",
                "match_mapping_type": "string",
                "mapping": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "norms": false
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "string_fields": {
                "match": "*",
                "match_mapping_type": "string",
                "mapping": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "norms": false,
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "properties": {
        "@timestamp": {
            "type": "date"
        },
        "@version": {
            "type": "keyword"
        },
        "source_host": {
            "type": "keyword"
        },
        "message": {
            "type": "text"
        },
        "thread_name": {
            "type": "text"
        },
        "level": {
            "type": "keyword"
        },
        "logger_name": {
            "type": "keyword"
        },
        "aplication_name": {
            "type": "keyword"
        },
        "exception": {
            "dynamic": true,
            "properties": {
                "exception_class": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "exception_message": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "stacktrace": {
                    "type": "text"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Elasticsearch responds with `"acknowledged": true` and I can see the template being updated via API.
Now starting logstash with `debug` log level i see the input logs being read but not sent to elasticsearch, although the index is created but it's always empty(0 documents):

```
[2019-12-03T09:30:51,655][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.file     ][custom] Received line {:path=>"/etc/logstash/input.log", :text=>"{\"@version\":1,\"source_host\":\"ubuntu\",\"message\":\"Generating some logs: 65778 - 2019-12-03T09:30:50.775\",\"thread_name\":\"parallel-1\",\"@timestamp\":\"2019-12-03T09:30:50.775+00:00\",\"level\":\"INFO\",\"logger_name\":\"nl.hnf.logs.aggregator.demo.LoggingTest\",\"aplication-name\":\"demo-log-aggregation\"}"}
[2019-12-03T09:30:51,656][DEBUG][filewatch.sincedbcollection][custom] writing sincedb (delta since last write = 1575365451)
```

Also, the elasticsearch logs are on `debug` level too, but i don't see any errors there or anything that could give me a hint about the source of the problem.

Do you guys have any idea or suggestion on why the logs are not pushed to elasticsearch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue by using `json` codec instead of `json_lines` and also removing `start_position`, `ignore_older` and `sincedb_path`

```
input {
  file {
    codec => "json"
    path => ["/etc/logstash/input.log"]
  }
}
output {
   elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["192.168.169.46:9200"]
   }
   stdout {
      codec => rubydebug
   }
}
```

Also the `json_lines` codec seems to be incompatible with the file input(`\n` separator it's not working as expected)

Answer (score 1):

In filebeat, setting ignore_older to zero means "do not check how old the file is". For a logstash file input, it means "ignore files more than zero seconds old", which is effectively "ignore everything". Delete it. If that does not help, then increase the log level to trace, and see what the filewatch module says about the files it is monitoring.

Comment: OK, turned the logs on `trace` level in logstash and removed the `ignore_older` config, still the same issues.
The filewatch modules reads the logs as expected(when they grow), but there are no logs regarding the output of data(the outputs are detected and configured by logstash correctly) .